# Как добавить класс для клика JS

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код: 2 карточки с идентичными классами. В данный момент по клику новые классы добавятся к обоим картам, а нужно чтобы по клику на конкретную карточку на нее выполнялась функция и добавлялись классы, а вторая осталась в стандартном состоянии.

По условию менять классы на второй карточке и вешать второй обработчик нельзя.
**Код только на ванильном js.**
**Как реализовать?**
**Такой вариант возможен?:**

```
function changeProp(event) {
  const card = event.target

  card.querySelector('.card-something').classList.toggle('some-class')
};
```

**?**

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

const cardSlogan = document.querySelector('.card__slogan');
const cardText = document.querySelector('.card__text');
const cardImg = document.querySelector('.card__img');

function changeProp() {
  cardSlogan.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.toggle('changeBorder');
  });

  cardText.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.toggle('changeColor');
  });

  cardImg.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.toggle('changeSize');
  });
}

card.addEventListener('click', changeProp);
```

```html
  <section class="section-card">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__slogan"></div>
    <div class="card__text"></div>
    <div class="card__img"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__slogan"></div>
    <div class="card__text"></div>
    <div class="card__img"></div>
  </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: А можно ли изменить элемент, на котором устанавливается слушатель? Ибо в данном расположении дел, без двух слушателей не обойтись.

Comment: Да можно. Еще можно карточки обернуть родительским дивом <div class="section-card"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы не можем вешать два слушателя, то нам нужно повесить слушатель на `document` (в лучшем случае, на контейнер, в котором будут находится данные элементы) и внутри проверять, был бы ли клик по элементу с классом `card` (Забыл как это называется).  Если же клик был по элементу с таким классом, мы ищем в нем элементы с нужными нам классом и что-то делаем с ними.

```js
function changeProp({target}) {
  if (target.classList.contains('card') === false) {
    return;
  }

  target.querySelector('.card__slogan')?.classList.toggle('changeBorder')
  target.querySelector('.card__text')?.classList.toggle('changeColor');
  target.querySelector('.card__img')?.classList.toggle('changeSize');
}

document.addEventListener('click', changeProp);
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__slogan"></div>
  <div class="card__text"></div>
  <div class="card__img"></div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card__slogan"></div>
  <div class="card__text"></div>
  <div class="card__img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если повешать второй слушатель, классы у дивов нужно менять обязательно?

Comment: Не понял вопрос.

Comment: В целом, вы не можете на коллекцию элементов повесить сразу слушатель, вам нужно перебрать коллекцию и на каждый элемент повесить слушатель. Что нарушает условия задачи.

Comment: Какой самый оптимальный вариант в такой ситуации в целом (не конкретно в этой ситуации)? Давать блокам с карточками разные классы и на каждый вешать свой слушатель?

Comment: Смотря в чем именно заключается задача.

Comment: Задача в том чтобы по клику на одну из допустим десяти карточек новый класс добавился только на нее.

Comment: В данном случае, лучше повесить слушатель на контейнер-обвёртку.

Comment: Плюсы при одном слушателе на контейнере обвертке, если внутрь блока динамически добавятся блоки, все будет по прежнему работать, если же добавлять слушатель на каждый элемент (карточку), то на новые элементы при создании нужно будет добавлять обработчик, не очень то и удобно.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, поставьте ему стрелочку вверх и если он решает вашу проблему - галочку.